# Django taggit view leading to FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: name

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-taggit

Tag view leads to this error message.
The `FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: name` indicates a mismatch between what the Django ORM expects for a query on the tags relation and the actual query being executed.

```
[...]
 File "/workspace/Coach-Matrix/main_forum/views/filters.py", line 18, in get_queryset
    return Question.objects.filter(tags__name=tag.name)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1420, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1438, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1445, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1562, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1478, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1292, in build_lookup
    raise FieldError(

Exception Type: FieldError at /questions/tag/tag4/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: name
```

---

I had tried Fetching the Tag instance using its slug and Using the name of the fetched Tag instance to filter Question objects.

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from ..models import Question
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from taggit.models import Tag

class FilterByTagView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'filtered_questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag_slug = self.kwargs.get('tag_slug')
        # Retrieve the Tag object by slug
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        # Use TaggedItemManager's filter method to get questions tagged with the retrieved tag
        return Question.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag.slug)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tag_slug = self.kwargs.get('tag_slug')
        context['tag'] = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because the Django `filter()` method is being used with `tags__name`, which isn't a valid lookup for the tags relation established by [`django-taggit`](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

django-taggit doesn't store tags directly on the model but instead uses a through-model to associate tags with objects. This means you cannot directly use `tags__name` or `tags__slug` in a `filter()` call, at least for most obvious cases.

This approach confirmed as working, it involved using taggit's TaggedItem model to find all items tagged with a specific tag and then filtering the Question objects based on that:

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from ..models import Question
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from taggit.models import Tag, TaggedItem # added Taggeditem to find all items tagged with a specific tag

class FilterByTagView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'filtered_questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag_slug = self.kwargs.get('tag_slug')
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)

        # Use TaggedItem to query all items associated with the tag:
        questions_ids = TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag_id=tag.id).values_list('object_id', flat=True)

        return Question.objects.filter(id__in=questions_ids) # return id in question_id's

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tag_slug = self.kwargs.get('tag_slug')
        context['tag'] = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        return context
```